# Google map's route optimization

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have 4 places - origin, destination and 2 waypoints. I am trying to make Google Directions API call to get the most optimal route through those two waypoints. The problem is that Google API doesn't reorder my waypoints according to the optimal route, but it creates a route including the waypoints in the initial order that I defined in the call.

The wanted route is as following:

Origin
Waypoint 2
Waypoint 1
Destination
Received route output is as following:

Origin
Waypoint 1
Waypoint 2
Destination
Here is the API call I tried: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=46.3526877,16.8123505&destination=46.3091764,16.3420242&waypoints=optimize:true%7Cvia:46.3380636%2C16.6129778%7Cvia:46.3258985%2C16.7827804&alternatives=true&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

I tried adding "optimizeWaypoints" parameter but I always get an empty "waypoint_order" array (which should contain waypoints in the correct order so that the route will be optimal according to the documentation).

Here is the API call with "optimizeWaypoints" parameter added: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=46.3526877,16.8123505&destination=46.3091764,16.3420242&waypoints=via:46.3380636%2C16.6129778%7Cvia:46.3258985%2C16.7827804&alternatives=true&optimizeWaypoints=true&key=GOOGLE_API_KEY

I HAVE TRIED TO USE DIRECTION API AND ALSO TRIED TO USE OPTIMIZED :TRUE BUT DIDN'T WORK

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the [Directions API (webservice)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions) is `optimize:true`.
The syntax for the [Directions Service (Javascript API v3)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) is `optimizeWaypoints:true`

See the [example in the documentation for the webservice](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#OptimizeWaypoints):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json
  ?destination=Adelaide%2C%20SA
  &origin=Adelaide%2C%20SA
  &waypoints=optimize%3Atrue%7CBarossa%20Valley%2C%20SA%7CClare%2C%20SA%7CConnawarra%2C%20SA%7CMcLaren%20Vale%2C%20SA
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

(notice the lack of `via:`)

Remove the `via:` from your waypoints and it works:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=46.3526877,16.8123505&destination=46.3091764,16.3420242&waypoints=optimize:true%7C46.3380636%2C16.6129778%7C46.3258985%2C16.7827804&alternatives=true&key=API_KEY

`"waypoint_order" : [ 1, 0 ]`

(the `alternatives=true` also seems like it isn't useful, you can't get route alternatives with waypoints, but it seems to "work" with that, at least currently)

on `via:` [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#influence-routes-with-stopover-and-pass-through-points_1) states:

> **Influence routes with stopover and pass through points**
> For each waypoint in the request, the directions response appends an entry to the legs array to provide the details for stopovers on that leg of the journey.
> If you'd like to influence the route using waypoints without adding a stopover, add the prefix via: to the waypoint. Waypoints prefixed with via: will not add an entry to the legs array, but will route the journey through the waypoint.
> The via: prefix is most effective when creating routes in response to the user dragging the waypoints on the map. Doing so allows the user to see how the final route may look in real-time and helps ensure that waypoints are placed in locations that are accessible to the Directions API.
> **Caution:** Using the via: prefix to avoid stopovers results in directions that are strict in their interpretation of the waypoint. This interpretation may result in severe detours on the route or ZERO_RESULTS in the response status code if the Directions API is unable to create directions through that point.

(doesn't seem useful with `optimize:true`)